# Using concurrent::map() with a list of QModelIndexes

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am trying to use concurrent::run() on a list of QModelIndexes.  The function I'm trying to call looks like this:

```
writeXML(QModelIndex &index)
```

My map code looks like:

```
QModelIndexList list;
QFutureWatcher<void> futureWatcher;
futureWatcher.setFuture(QtConcurrent::map(list, list->writeXML() ));

futureWatcher.waitForFinished();
```

I'm getting a compile error saying "No matching function for call to writeXML().

I have looked at this tutorial which I found useful: http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QtConcurrent_QFutureWatcher_QProgressDialog_map.php

But I don't yet understand how the index get passed to the function, in my case writeXML() ?

What do I need to do with my code above to get this at least compiling?

Comment: I'd be very careful, since a non-persistent `QModelIndex` is not valid as soon as there are any structural changes to the model. Are you ensuring that the model's structure will remain locked down until the processing is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QModelIndexList` is just a `typedef` for `QList<QModelIndex>` and of course `QList` has no `writeXML` method, because it is your custom function. You need one container (`list`) and one function (`writeXML`), so it should be.

```
QModelIndexList list;
QFutureWatcher<void> futureWatcher;
futureWatcher.setFuture(QtConcurrent::map(list, writeXML));
//valid only if writeXML is a function, not a class member function!

futureWatcher.waitForFinished();
```

Another example:

```
QMutex mutex;
void writeXML(QModelIndex & index)
{
    QMutexLocker lock(&mutex);
    qDebug() << index.data();
}
//...
{
    //somewhere

    //get list of indexes
    QModelIndexList list = ui->tableView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
    QFutureWatcher<void> futureWatcher;
    //apply writeXML to each index
    futureWatcher.setFuture(QtConcurrent::map(list, writeXML));

    futureWatcher.waitForFinished();
}
```

Comment: OK, I get this, thank you.  But in writeXML() how do I know which one of the indexes in the list has been passed into the function?

Comment: @MichaelVincent concurrent::map will iterate throw the list and pass every index to your function. Something like: `foreach(QModelIndex & ind,list) writeXML(ind);` but in another thread.

Comment: Thank you, @Chernobyl.  What should the declaration of my writeXML() look like?  void writeXML(QModelIndex & index)  ?

Comment: @MichaelVincent Yes, I added more details to my answer. See it please.